# Object that contains an array of arrays, how to remove object so it's only an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, puppeteer

I have an object that contains an array of arrays. I would like to remove the object so it's only an array of arrays. Is there a way in JavaScript to do this or am I out of luck? I'm using Puppeteer to scrape a page and return all the text after mapping through a set of elements. I've already written a function to seprate it into the arrays I want but Puppeteer returns it as an object which I don't want.
The object it returns looks like this

**UPDATE**

Turns out it's returning a promise which is an object.
So the result that I get when I log to the console is

```
Promise {
    [ [], [], []... ]
}
```

So I guess my new question is how do I get only the result of the promise.

```
data = {
  [
    [], [], []...
  ]
};
```

I would like it to look like

```
data = [
  [], [], []...
]
```

*Puppeteer function*

```
const getText = async (data) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(data.URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    const options = await page.$$eval('table[class="data-table"] > tbody > tr > td', (options) =>
        options.map((option) => option.textContent)
    );    
    await browser.close();
    const finalData = createGroups(options, 228);
    // the puppeteer function returns each texContent as a single array, meaning the page 
    // I'm scraping returns 1140 arrays, I want each array in my final product to contain 5 
    // elements so I did 1140/5, that's how I got 228
    console.log(finalData);
}
```

*createGroups function*

```
const createGroups = async (arr, numGroups) => {
    const perGroup = Math.ceil(arr.length / numGroups);
    const finalArr = new Array(numGroups)
      .fill('')
      .map((_, i) => arr.slice(i * perGroup, (i + 1) * perGroup));
    return finalArr;
}
```

Or is there is a way to just extract that large array which contains the smaller arrays and put that into it's own variable? The way to do it with arrays would be `LargeArray[0]` but I don't know how to do that with objects.

Thanks

Comment: The structure `{ [...] }` is not possibile, are you sure its not something like this: `{ someKey: [...] }` because an object needs to have keys

Comment: I just looked again and it looks like it's returning a promise, when I log it to the console I get
```Promise {
  [
    [ 'Afghanistan', '0', '312', '+312', '' ],...```

Comment: Either you can use await or whatever result you are getting apply .then()
Example: yourResult.then((data) => {
here data will be array of arrays
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting a `Promise` returned is that your `createGroups` is `async` (without a need to be), and the return type of an `async` function is always a `Promise`.

The best way is to just change it to not be `async`

```js
const createGroups = (arr, numGroups) => { // rest of code
```

If for whatever reason, you don't want to do this, you can just `await` it in your main method.

```js
const finalData = await createGroups(options, 228);
```

In almost every circumstance I can think of, the only times you should use `async` are:

- You're using `await` somewhere in the method
- You're passing the function as a callback to another function, which expects the callback to return a `Promise` and you don't want to create the `Promise` manually